# Calendário javascript conflito entre parâmetros aspas simples x aspas duplas

Tags: javascript

Preciso ajustar/adaptar o calendário abaixo.
É javascript puro

Na figura 1, ele e totalmente funcional... Ou seja, 
Carrega data a partir do value do input. 
Navega entre meses e anos e seleciona data. 
[image: calendário antigo]

Ocorre que preciso utilizá-lo na estrutura do bootstrap (4)..

1º problema: Ele desformata... Creio eu que o principal motivo é porque ele usa tag `<table>`, `<tr>` e `<td>`

2º problema: Preciso trabalhar também com o horário. Ou seja: Data + hora.

Então refiz o layout do calendários utilizando divs... 
Na figura 2 ele esta carregando inicialmente com data e hora. 
[image: caledário novo]
Mas ao add funcionalidades de navegação ocorre erros os quais gostaria de colaboração para sana-los.

1º ponto: 
Inicialmente,  comparando as chamadas das funções no html tenho os parâmetros semelhantes – que funcionam:

Antigo:

```
<input type="button" name="btnData1" id="btnData1" value="." onclick="popdate('data_ini','pop1','150',document.getElementById('data_ini').value)">
```

Onde:  popdate() 
1º parâmetro = objeto
2º parâmetro = div
3º parâmetro = tamanho (pixel) 
4º parâmetro = data

Novo:

```
<button class="btn btnrimary" onclick="popdataJGD('dataHoraINI','pop1',document.getElementById('dataHoraINI').value)">
```

Onde: popdataJGD()
1º parâmetro = objeto
2º parâmetro = div
3º parâmetro = data hora

2º Ponto: 
Internamente (dentro da função) 
O comando de voltar um mês ‘<’... 
Antigo:

```
...
txt += "<td width=20% align=center><a href=javascript:popdate('"+obj2+"','"+div+"','"+tam+"','"+( "01/" + (month_prior+1).toString() + "/" + year_prior.toString())+"') class='Cabecalho_Calendario' title='Mês Anterior'><</a></td>"
...
```

Os parâmetros são objeto, div tamanho, data… todos passados com aspas simples.

Novo:

```
...
txt += '<span class="control item2" title="Voltar mês">';
        txt += '<a href=javascript:popdataJGD("'+ obj2 + '","'+ div +'","' + dt_prior2 +' '+ mmm +"')><</a></span>';
    ...
```

Já aqui (novo)… Se utilize aspas duplas, na tela no ultimo parâmetro, a conversão codificada não considera a hora como parte do value... Ou, ao contrario solicita “)“.

a) Deduzo que estou chamando a função recursivamente (perdão se estiver errado)...

b) Se a forma de chamar é praticamente igual... Com é interpretado o ultimo parâmetro: document.getElementById('data_ini').value  ? É string, inteiro ou objeto tb ???

c) Inicialmente ao chamar a função pelo botão... Antes de exibir o calendário pela primeira vez..  Ao “printar” no console o parâmetro passado. 
Imprime como string: tipo data normal + espaço + hora...  Daí trato separadamente. Passando o valor tb tratado para o parâmetro interno. Ou seja, com a adição do espaço... Ocorre o mesmo conflito com as aspas simples e aspas duplas.  Tb tentei “escapar” (/)... Não funcionou.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda a respeito.

Comment: Vc cita "figuras" na pergunta mas não há nenhuma figura. :/

Comment: Também está muito confusa a pergunta. Eu não consegui entender direito qual o ponto da pergunta, qual o problema exatamente.

Comment: Perdão:  Basicamente é conflito de aspas que não acho explicação... Porque no antigo funciona... no novo só há a inversão das aspas...

Comment: Exibindo o source da tela após carregamento:
<a href="javascript:popdataJGD(dataHoraINI,pop1,01/01/2019" 09:00)="">&lt;</a>
Observar que data possui aspas adicionadas na interpretação do codigo.
Daí dá erro: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ")" after argument list

Comment: Pelo que vejo, as aspas deveriam ficar assim: `txt += '<a href="javascript:popdataJGD(\''+ obj2 + '\',\''+ div +'\',\'' + dt_prior2 +' '+ mmm +'\')"><</a></span>';`

Comment: Aspas duplas para delimitar o `href` e aspas simples escapadas nos parâmetros. Agora, ao colocar aspas nos parâmetros, eles serão enviados como string para a função `popdataJGD`.

Comment: Mas você não pode utilizar **template literals**?!

Answer (score 0):

Não recomendaria, essa bagunça com para concatenar uma string que pode ser interpolada.
Isso vai deixar o seu código mais legível e menos suscetível a esse tipo de erro. Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```js
let obj2 = 'teste';
let dt_prior2 = '23/03/2019';
let mmm = '123';

let txt = 
`<span class="control item2" title="Voltar mês">
    <a href="javascript:popdataJGD('${obj2}','div','${dt_prior2} ${mmm}');"> link </a>
</span>`;
            
console.log(txt);

document.getElementById("exemplo").innerHTML = txt
```

```html
<div id="exemplo"></div>
```

Comment: Simplificando: 
3º parâmentro assim: document.getElementById('dataHoraINI').value... Me parece inteior. Correto?
então... Como poderia passar este 3º parâmentro como string e inline... A data e a hora ???

Comment: Olá Leandro Angelo... Não entendi a notação... por exemplo: '${dt_prior2} ${mmm]'  equivale a document.getElementById('dataHoraINI').value ? Ou seria $(#dataHoraINI).val()? com esta notação.. da erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  linha: txt += '<a href="javascript:popdataJGD('obj2','div'dt_prior2 mmm);"><</a></span>';

Comment: representa o que você botou na pergunta, `"' + dt_prior2 +' '+ mmm +"'`. Se você editar colocando o trecho relevante do código ao invés de tentar explicar, dá para melhorar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, 
Solução indicada pelo Sam funcionou.
Valeu Sam!!!

Pode não ser a mais correta em termos de praticas... Como o Lenadro Angelo comentou... 
Mas as navegações internas do calendário estão funcionado em todos os sentidos... E o melhor data e hora juntas.

```
Pelo que vejo, as aspas deveriam ficar assim: txt += '<a href="javascript:popdataJGD(\''+ obj2 + '\',\''+ div +'\',\'' + dt_prior2 +' '+ mmm +'\')"><</a></span>'; – Sam
```